# Azure functions python SDK force response to make POST instead of GET

Tags: python, python-requests, azure-functions, single-sign-on

I am trying to write an azure function to manage SSO between two services. The first one will host the link to the HTTP triggered Azure Function which then should respond with the formatted SAML Response which then gets sent to the consumption URL as a POST, but I can only make GET requests with the azure.functions.HttpResponse method needed to parse outputs for Azure Functions (unless I'm wrong).

Alternatively I've tried to set the cookie that I get as a response from sending the SAML Response with the python requests method, but the consumption URL doesn't seem to care that the cookie is there and just brings me back to the login page.

The SP in this situation is Absorb LMS and I can confirm that the SAML Response is formatted correctly because submitting it from an HTTP form works fine (which I've also tried returning as the body of the azure.functions.HttpResponse, but I just get HTTP errors which I can't make heads or tails of).

```
import requests
import azure.functions as func

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
body = {"SAMLResponse": *b64 encoded saml response and assertion*}

response = requests.post(url=*acs url*, headers=headers, data=body)
headers = response.headers
headers['Location'] = *acs url*
return func.HttpResponse(headers=headers, status_code=302)
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No I didn't! I actually just wound up returning in the response an HTML form with the URL returned from the SSO as a hyperlink for the user to click which then redirects them to the endpoint with their sessions set up. I had some back and forth with Azure teams about this and there's no setup that they were aware of for returning to the user a POST.